# JTable losing focus after a button press

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a jtable with a custom editor and renderer applied to a column to turn the column's contents into a Button, however once i press on any of the buttons, the table loses focus, and the only interactive object in the panel is the button that was just clicked on, which can be clicked on repeatedly.

Here is the button renderer code:

```
public class ButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    private Border dsd_originalBorder;
    private int in_mnemonic;
    private Border dsd_focusBorder;

    private JButton dsd_renderButton;

    /**
     * empty constructor
     */
    public ButtonRenderer() {
        dsd_renderButton = new JButton();
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable dsd_table, Object dsd_value,
            boolean bo_isSelected, boolean bo_hasFocus, int in_row, int in_column) {

        if (!WorkplaceConstants.STR_INACTIVE.equals(dsd_table.getValueAt(in_row, dsd_table
                .getColumn(Main.hm_language.get(Language.STATUS))
                .getModelIndex())))
            return new JLabel("");

        if (bo_isSelected) {
            dsd_renderButton.setForeground(dsd_table.getSelectionForeground());
            dsd_renderButton.setBackground(dsd_table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            dsd_renderButton.setForeground(dsd_table.getForeground());
            dsd_renderButton.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        }

        if (bo_hasFocus) {
            dsd_renderButton.setBorder(dsd_focusBorder);
        } else {
            dsd_renderButton.setBorder(dsd_originalBorder);
        }

        // renderButton.setText( (value == null) ? "" : value.toString() );
        if (dsd_value == null) {
            dsd_renderButton.setText("");
            dsd_renderButton.setIcon(null);
        } else if (dsd_value instanceof Icon) {
            dsd_renderButton.setText("");
            dsd_renderButton.setIcon((Icon) dsd_value);
        } else {
            dsd_renderButton.setText(dsd_value.toString());
            dsd_renderButton.setIcon(null);
        }
        return dsd_renderButton;

    }

    /**
     * returns the mnemonic to activate the button when the cell has focus
     * 
     * @return the mnemonic
     */
    public int m_getMnemonic() {
        return in_mnemonic;
    }

    /**
     * The mnemonic to activate the button when the cell has focus
     * 
     * @param p_in_mnemonic
     *            the mnemonic
     */
    public void m_setMnemonic(int p_in_mnemonic) {
        this.in_mnemonic = p_in_mnemonic;
        dsd_renderButton.setMnemonic(p_in_mnemonic);
    }

    /**
     * Get foreground color of the button when the cell has focus
     * 
     * @return the foreground color
     */
    public Border m_getFocusBorder() {
        return dsd_focusBorder;
    }

    /**
     * The foreground color of the button when the cell has focus
     * 
     * @param dsd_focusBorder
     *            the foreground color
     */
    public void m_setFocusBorder(Border dsd_focusBorder) {
        this.dsd_focusBorder = dsd_focusBorder;
    }
```

Here is the button Editor code:

```
public class ButtonEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor, ActionListener, MouseListener{

    private JTable dsd_table;
    private int in_mnemonic;
    private Border dsd_originalBorder;
    private Border dsd_focusBorder;

    private JButton dsd_editButton;
    private Object dsd_editorValue;
    private boolean bo_isButtonColumnEditor;


    /**
     * Constructor 
     * @param dsdp_table the table to which the editor is going to be applied.
     * @param action the action which is to be executed when the button is clicked
     */
    public ButtonEditor(JTable dsdp_table) {
        this.dsd_table = dsdp_table;
        dsd_editButton = new JButton();
        dsd_editButton.setFocusPainted( false );
        dsd_editButton.addActionListener( this );
        dsd_originalBorder = dsd_editButton.getBorder();
        m_setFocusBorder( new LineBorder(Color.BLUE) );

        dsdp_table.addMouseListener( this );
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return dsd_editorValue;
    }

    /**
     * returns the mnemonic to activate the button when the cell has focus
     * 
     * @return the mnemonic
     */
    public int m_getMnemonic()
    {
        return in_mnemonic;
    }

    /**
     *  The mnemonic to activate the button when the cell has focus
     *
     *  @param in_mnemonic the mnemonic
     */
    public void m_setMnemonic(int in_mnemonic)
    {
        this.in_mnemonic = in_mnemonic;
        dsd_editButton.setMnemonic(in_mnemonic);
    }

    /**
     * Get foreground color of the button when the cell has focus
     * 
     * @return the foreground color
     */
    public Border m_getFocusBorder() {
        return dsd_focusBorder;
    }

    /**
     * The foreground color of the button when the cell has focus
     * 
     * @param dsdp_focusBorder
     *            the foreground color
     */
    public void m_setFocusBorder(Border dsdp_focusBorder) {
        this.dsd_focusBorder = dsdp_focusBorder;
        dsd_editButton.setBorder(dsdp_focusBorder);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int in_modelRow = dsd_table.convertRowIndexToModel( dsd_table.getEditingRow() );
        fireEditingStopped();
        // Here i start a custom thread to run in the background.
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if (dsd_table.isEditing() && dsd_table.getCellEditor() == this)
            bo_isButtonColumnEditor = true;

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        if (bo_isButtonColumnEditor && dsd_table.isEditing())
            dsd_table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();

        bo_isButtonColumnEditor = false;

    }

    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener arg0) {
    }

    public void cancelCellEditing() {
    }

    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener arg0) {
    }

    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        return false;
    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable dsd_table, Object dsd_value,
            boolean bo_isSelected, int in_row, int in_column) {

        if (!WorkplaceConstants.STR_INACTIVE.equals(dsd_table.getValueAt(in_row, dsd_table
                .getColumn(Main.hm_language.get(Language.STATUS))
                .getModelIndex())))
            return new JLabel("");


        if (dsd_value == null)
        {
            dsd_editButton.setText( "" );
            dsd_editButton.setIcon( null );
        }
        else if (dsd_value instanceof Icon)
        {
            dsd_editButton.setText( "" );
            dsd_editButton.setIcon( (Icon)dsd_value );
        }
        else
        {
            dsd_editButton.setText( dsd_value.toString() );
            dsd_editButton.setIcon( null );
        }

        bo_isButtonColumnEditor = true;

        this.dsd_editorValue = dsd_value;
        dsd_editButton.setBorder(dsd_originalBorder);
        return dsd_editButton;
    }


    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e){
        return true;
    }

    public Border m_getoriginalBorder() {
        return dsd_originalBorder;
    }

    public void m_set_originalBorder(Border dsd_originalBorder) {
        this.dsd_originalBorder = dsd_originalBorder;
    }


}
```

Here is how i am assigning the editor and renderer to the table

```
public static void m_setButtonColumnConfiguration(JTable table) {
        ButtonEditor dsd_btn_edit = new ButtonEditor(table);
        dsd_btn_edit.m_setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        table.getColumn(/*i get the identifier for the column here*/).setCellEditor(dsd_btn_edit);
        ButtonRenderer dsd_btn_rend = new ButtonRenderer();
        dsd_btn_rend.m_setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        table.getColumn(/*i get the identifier for the column here*/)
                .setCellRenderer(dsd_btn_rend);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

> Button, however once i press on any of the buttons, the table loses focus

Yes, anytime you click on a component it gets focus, so this makes sense.

> and the only interactive object in the panel is the button that was just clicked on,

Not sure I understand this statement. You can click on the table again and it will regain focus. You can then navigate around the table.

Maybe you are just suggesting the button renderer/editor isn't working the way you expect. We can't test this because you didn't post a `SSCCE`.

Anyway, check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for another example of a button renderer/editor that responds to mouse clicks or key board events.

Comment: After the button action listener is executed, I cannot get any feedback from any parts of the table apart from the button. The table for example highlights the row you click on. That is no longer showing. The other buttons in the same column also no longer execute their functionality

Comment: With regards to the example you gave I see no differences.

Comment: I added some more detail. would i need to add something else for it to be an SSCCE?

Comment: @mangusbrother, we need to be able to complile and execute a simple version of the code that demonstrates the problem. For example get rid of the Thread that you start in the ActionListener.

Comment: this should compile for you. That thread is only mentioned in the comment. It was removed from the snipped specifically so it wouldn't compile. It has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: oh god... within all this time spent complaining about there not being 5 frickin standard lines of code you could have scanned through it and tried to see if anything was wrong.

Comment: @mangusbrother, if you would have posted a proper SSCCE when you posted the question you probably would have had an answer now. I already gave you a solution. The solution I gave you works perfectly fine for me (and others in the forum). I have no idea why it doesn't work for you, so the problem is in the code you didn't post. And that is why you post a SSCCE, because I can't guess what your code looks like. `you could have scanned through it and tried to see if anything was wrong` - I did. I guess I'm not a smart as you, I need to be able to debug code to solve a problem.